# Estou com dificuldades para fazer a comparação de dois números no php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Sou iniciante no php e estou tentando fazer a comparação de dois números porém quando envio os números para minha outra página acaba dando erro, gostaria de ajuda e se possível uma explicação bem detalhada de qual foi meu erro.

Erro:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Maior::maior() e Notice: Undefined variable

Página:

```
<?php require_once 'maior.php'; ?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exemplo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label>Informe o primeiro número</label><br/>      
      <input type="text" placeholder="Primeiro número" name="primeiroNumero" value="">
    </p>    
    <p>
      <label>Informe o segundo número</label><br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo número" name="segundoNumero" value=""><br>
    </p>    
    <input type="submit"></input><br>
  </form>        
  <?php
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

    if (isset($post)) {    
      $primeiroNumero = $post["primeiroNumero"];
      $segundoNumero = $post["segundoNumero"];                
   ?><br/>
 <div>
 <?php
   $maior = new Maior();
   $maior->maior($primeiroNumero, $segundoNumero);
 ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Página 2, contém a comparação e é onde o navegador diz que está o erro:

```
<?php
class Maior {    
     function maior($primeiroNumero, $segundoNumero){
        if ($primeiroNumero > $segundoNumero){
            echo "O primeiro número é maior que o segundo";
        }
        elseif($segundoNumero > $primeiroNumero){
            echo "O segundo número é maior que o primeiro";
        }
        else
            echo "Os números tem os mesmo valores";
    }   
}
```

Comment: qual é o erro que está dando? poderia copia-lo por favor?

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Maior::maior() e Notice: Undefined variable

Answer (score 1):

O método está com o mesmo nome da classe, então, ele é interpretado como um método o método mágico `__construct`. Altere o nome do método `maior()` ou da classe, para não obter mais este erro.

**Edit:** veja mais sobre construtores em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php

**Nota:** por boa prática, defina a visibilidade do método, ex:

```
   public function comparaValores($primeiroNumero, $segundoNumero){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que sua variável no código principal está com o mesmo nome do método e também falta o construtor na sua classe. Tente salvar os seguintes códigos:

```
<?php
class Maior{

    public $primeiroNumero;
    public $segundoNumero;

    public function __construct($primeiroNumero,$segundoNumero){
       $this->primeiroNumero = $primeiroNumero;
       $this->segundoNumero = $segundoNumero;
    } 

    public function maior() {

        if($this->primeiroNumero > $this->segundoNumero){
            return "O primeiro número é maior que o segundo";
        }
        elseif($this->segundoNumero > $this->primeiroNumero){
            return "O segundo número é maior que o primeiro";
        }
        else{
            return "Os números tem os mesmo valores";
         }
    }   
}
?>
```

e na sua página principal:

```
    $most = new Maior(10,15);
    $valueMaior = $most->maior();
    echo $valueMaior;
```

Comment: Ikaro, o construtor não é obrigatório.